# Login via Xamarin Android UI instead of server side login page, IdentityServer4, ASP.NET CORE

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, identityserver4

I wonder if it is possible to use Xamarin Android UI as a login page instead of getting directed to server side login page, which allows the mobile app to authenticate users by communicating with server side behind the scenes.

The reason is that we want to avoid the redirecting from mobile to server side, and back to mobile app.

Can anyone provide links on how to implement this case in single sign on?

https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples

Comment: Do you want to do this in Server or in Xamarin?From newest identityserver4 API document(https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/signin.html#login-user-interface-and-identity-management-system), this also need be redirected to the login page.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bc8tv.png)From Xamarin `WebView` can do that in Android UI ,but also need to redirect to login page.Because API need to use redirect to finish authenticating.By interact with `Javascript`,webview page can back to other view in current Application.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using `password` grant type (aka resource owner credentials grant). In order to do that you need to add this grant to the client:

`AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,`

And in addition to that, you will need to implement `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` interface in order to supply implementation which will validate the incoming credentials for this grant type.

You can then programatically call the `/connect/token` endpoint in your app instead of going through redirects.

Before you embark on implementing this though, please research the concerns around the usage of this grant type as it is generally frowned upon and not recommended.

From [Identity Server 4 documenation:](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html)

> The resource owner password grant type allows to request tokens on
>   behalf of a user by sending the user’s name and password to the token
>   endpoint. **This is so called “non-interactive” authentication and is
>   generally not recommended**

And also various articles on [Why the Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant Type is not Authentication nor Suitable for Modern Applications](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications)

Comment: Below is an example for this, but it doesn't implement IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator and use /connect/token. https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/master/Quickstarts/2_ResourceOwnerPasswords

Comment: Will using certificate for communication between server and mobile eliminate the security issue? also the login credentials are entered by users not hardcoded.

Comment: @Pingpong it won't eliminate the security issue because it will not likely be possible to install certificate on each mobile device that the user will use. At best you will only be able to minimize the security risks but doubt you will ever be able to eliminate them should you choose to take this approach. That is one of the reasons why this grant type is not recommended.

Comment: sorry for missing the information. Our firm manage all devices, and install certificate on all devices, and manage identity server,

Comment: What other grant type can be used?

Comment: You should look at using hybrid flow which combines multiple grant types.